# Click tracking with Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm new to GTM, coming from GA.

In GA, if I wanted to track clicks to a given element, I would place that code in an `onclick` event.

How would one accomplish this with a GTM tag?

Suppose I have:

```
<div id="click_me" >
    ** hot new content **
</div>
```

I would like to create a tag to track every time this element is clicked.

I have already set up the GTM container on my site, along with GA, and connected the two with a "Universal Analytics" tag, all of which seems to be correctly configured like so..

[image]

Where do I go from here?

Comment: You should read the documentation from Google. I think they are sufficient to resolve this very basic query. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6164470?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to this resource on how to create an event tag to track your clicks: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6164470?hl=en

Your trigger would be based on the ID that is clicked and could look something like this:
[image]